# Add UIButton to UITextView Dynamically with UserInteractionEnabled

Tags: dynamic, ios4, uibutton, uitextview

I am building an app where I need to add buttons to a UITextView dynamically on the basis of text entered by the user in the same UITextView.

The look I want to give is something like **To field in message app of iPhone**

I am unsable to figure out the way to do the needful.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution to my problem and no one has yet answered here so will reply to my own question.

I tried to keep a UITextView on a UIScrollView and then kept changing the width of the UItectView and added button to the left of it depending on the text added in the the textView. This will help in giving an appearance similar to that of a textfield with dynamic addition of UIButton.

Hope this wolrs for all those having the similar problem.